# trying to create a cron on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu

i've been trying to create a cron that doesn't seem to be working. i'm running Ubuntu 14.04. for testing i've set my cron to run every minute.

btw, i'd created the cron using, 'sudo crontab -e'. not sure if sudo was needed, but thought why not in case permissions might be an issue (by the way, the php script runs fine from command line without sudo)

here's a couple variations that I've tried, but don't work,

```
    1 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/test/index.php
    1 * * * * /var/www/html/test/index.php
```

and, here's my cron (the whole thing)...

```
    # Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
    # 
    # Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
    # indicating with different fields when the task will be run
    # and what command to run for the task
    # 
    # To define the time you can provide concrete values for
    # minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
    # and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').# 
    # Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
    # daemon's notion of time and timezones.
    # 
    # Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
    # email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
    # 
    # For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
    # at 5 a.m every week with:
    # 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
    # 
    # For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
    # 

    # m h  dom mon dow   command
    1 * * * * /var/www/html/test/index.php
    ~             
    ~
```

Comment: `sudo` is not needed for cron jobs if the jobs can be run under your normal account. "why not" is not a good reason to use `sudo` when you don't know.

Comment: Curious though: why do you want to run a PHP webpage as a cron job? If it's anything else than a webpage, I wouldn't stick it in `/var/www/`.

Comment: i wanted to test it using sudo just to see if permissions are getting in the way. i want to run a php script as a cron because its the scripting language i know (all the hokery pokery that i know is in php)... but i will be learning python very soon... i see the need for it now!

Answer (score 0):

If you have not already, try starting the cron service with this command `/etc/init.d/crond start`. Hope this helps, let us know if it doesn't.

Comment: tried the command just as you've typed it and here's the error message, -bash: /etc/init.d/crond: No such file or directory

Comment: Try it with sudo privileges.

Comment: get this error message... sudo: /etc/init.d/crond: command not found

Comment: just now tried... sudo /etc/init.d/cron reload ...didn't get any error messages, but nothing has happened after a minute

Comment: try 'sudo restart cron' or 'sudo start cron'. You can also add a simple job like '* * * * * /usr/bin/touch /tmp/cron' and check every minute if /tmp/cron has a new timestamp.

Comment: i got 'cron start/running, process 1889', with 'sudo restart cron', but still not seeing the cron work. am i supposed to make adjustments elsewhere? scratching my head with this

Answer (score 0):

just got it working. this is the correct code,

- - - - - php /var/www/html/test/index.php

was able to figure it out after reading this post... https://askubuntu.com/questions/430509/cannot-run-cron-job-for-a-php-script/430664#430664